# how to stop auto order fields in a model class?

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, arraylist

I created a model class (only show constructor here)

```
public PieceModel(int position, int piece_id) {
    this.position = position;
    this.piece_id = piece_id;
}
```

then add some data

```
list.add(new PieceModel(1, 100));
list.add(new PieceModel(2, 300));
list.add(new PieceModel(3, 600));
```

and then i convert list to string and it print like this

```
[{"piece_id":100,"position":1},{"piece_id":300,"position":2},{"piece_id":600,"position":3}]
```

but i need it like this

```
[{"position":1,"piece_id":100},{"position":2,"piece_id":200},{"position":3,"piece_id":300}]
```

some advice please..

Comment: Read up how to sort a list by using `Comparator`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) will help. Come back after you have read it up and if you're not able to implement it properly.

Comment: @Nicholas K I don't think he is talking about sorting. He just wants the properties to appear in the way he sets.

Comment: Does the property order matters, as you are still going to access it with names ?

Comment: @KiraAG: See the tags OP has used. It clearly says *sorting*.

Comment: @Nicholas K Ya I saw that, But the OP's ask states otherwise. I ll let the OP decide what he wants. Anyway thanks for referencing the link, I learnt something new.

Comment: yes i need property order to appear in the way i set, because i am trying to match that string with another string

Comment: Then you need to clearly implement the sorting the way @Nicholas K mentioned

Comment: What code do you use to "convert to `String`"? That's where the issue lies and that's where you need to solve it. Please show the code you use to convert `PieceModel` to `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? Override `toString` and re-arrange the properties?

```
static class PieceModel {
    private int position;
    private int piece_id;

    public PieceModel(int position, int piece_id) {
        this.position = position;
        this.piece_id = piece_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "position=" + position +
                ", piece_id=" + piece_id +
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<PieceModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new PieceModel(1, 100));
    list.add(new PieceModel(2, 300));
    list.add(new PieceModel(3, 600));
    System.out.print(list.toString());
}
```

Result:

```
[{"position":1,"piece_id":100},{"position":2,"piece_id":200},{"position":3,"piece_id":300}]
```

Comment: Not sure how he prints out the values, if `list.toString()`, I suppose to override toString() on the model class, else, yes, manually print out

Comment: yes that is what i need to know. it is working and now i can customize it. thank you @nhp

Comment: You're welcome :D